# NestJS getting param from array matching

Tags: nestjs

I don't know how to get matched param from this definition:

```
@Get(['FAVORITE', 'RATING', 'FAVORITE_AND_RATING'])
find(...): Promise<Array<any>> {
    /// how to get param what was matched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe just a workaround but it should work

```
@Get(['FAVORITE', 'RATING', 'FAVORITE_AND_RATING'])
find(@Param('FAVORITE') favorite: string, @Param('RATING') rating: string, 
     @Param('FAVORITE_AND_RATING') favorite_and_rating: string): Promise<Array<any>> {
    if(favorite) {
      //stuff to do
    } else if(rating) {
      //stuff to do
    } else if(favorite_and_rating) {
      //stuff to do
    }
}
```

Comment: @Get(['FAVORITE_AND_RATING'])
find(@Param('FAVORITE_AND_RATING') param: string, @Param() params) {
   console.log(param, params) //undefined, {}
}

Comment: I dont understand your problem. You have to describe it better

Comment: your workaround doesn't work. If I'm using @Param('FAVORITE_AND_RATING') then I got undefined.